Showing $ \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin x}-\frac{2x}{\pi}}{\pi^2-4x^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}$, without using L'Hôpital's rule

Show that
$$
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-\frac{2x}{\pi}}{\pi^2-4x^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}
$$

MY ATTEMPT
$$
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-\frac{2x}{\pi}}{\pi^2-4x^2}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-\frac{2x}{\pi}}{(\pi+2x) \times{(\pi-2x)}} 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \times
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-\frac{2x}{\pi}}{{(1-\frac{2x}{\pi})}} 
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \times
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-1+ \left(1-\frac{2x}{\pi}\right
)}{{(1-\frac{2x}{\pi})}} 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi^2} \times \left(
\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-1}{{(1-\frac{2x}{\pi})}} +\lim_{x \to \pi/2}1
\right)$$
Now $$
\sin{x}-1=\left(\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}-1 \right)\times \left({\sin^{\frac{2}{3}}(x)}+\sqrt[3]{\sin(x)}+1 \right)$$
from here how can I proceed to get it?
We can get the answer by factorizing the denominator and applying L'hôpital's rule.
How can I show that the last part is zero?

Hint: by the definition of the derivative,$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin x-\sin\pi/2}{x-\pi/2}=\sin'(\pi/2).$$

Given the work you've done, you're nearly there. Since most standard limits of trig functions are developed near $0$, let's first set $y = \pi/2 - x$ so that
$$ \frac{\sin^{1/3}(x) - 1}{1 - 2x/\pi} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cos^{1/3}(y) - 1}{y} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cos y - 1}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^{2/3} y + \cos^{1/3}(y) + 1}.$$
Now, as $y \to 0,$ the final term goes to $1/3$. Further, we have $$\frac{\cos y - 1}{y} =  \frac{\cos y -1}{y^2} \cdot y. $$ But $(\cos(y) - 1)/y^2 \to \frac12$ as $y \to 0$, and of course $y \to 0$, meaning that $(\cos y - 1)/y \to 0$ as $y \to 0$, and we can conclude that this part has the limit $0$.

Let $x=\pi/2-y$, then you need to find
$$
(*)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\cos(y)}-1+\frac{2y}{\pi}}{\pi^2-(\pi-2y)^2}
=
\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\cos(y)}-1+\frac{2y}{\pi}}{4y(\pi -y)}
=
\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\cos(y)}-1+\frac{2y}{\pi}}{4y\pi+O(y^2)}
$$
Next,
$$
\sqrt[3]{\cos(y)}-1=\frac{\cos y -1}{1+a+a^2}
=-\frac{2\sin^2(y/2)}{1+a+a^2}=O(y^2)\text{ as }y\to 0
$$
where $a=a(y)=\cos y$, since $a^3-1=(a-1)(1+a+a^2)$.
Hence
$$
(*)=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{O(y^2)+\frac{2y}{\pi}}{4y\pi+O(y^2)}=\frac1{2\pi^2}.
$$

Isn't the 2 in the denominator?

oops, it was a typo!
